# How to show row data in expand row when tapped based on some range of number just like below attached images

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[see this image for showing rows in expand and collapes on tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsRav.png)

I want to group property_identifier: range 0 to 150 as general ,then 151 to 300 as alarm and 300 to 500 as hitorian when i tapped on general then i want to see only 0 to 150 range of property identifier value in expand and colloaps form and when i clicked on alarm then i should see epanded row of alarm based on property_identifier range 151 to 300 and so on attaching  image below  and i want these thing dynamic.

I have api response json which i have mention property details in this property details having a field  property_identifier in key value pair , property_identifier having some number like 0 ,111, 100, and so on.. so what i want , i want to group them in three field General , alarm, hestorian when i tab on General i should see only property_identifier 0 to 150 row in general in expand formate just like above image same for alarm property_identifier 151 to 250 and when i click on alarm then i should see only these range rows in expand formate same for hestorian based on property_identifier range i want to group those rows and will show in expand and collapes formate just like above image.

property_details
{property_identifier: 111, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Status Flags'}
{property_identifier: 36, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event State'}
{property_identifier: 81, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Out Of Service'}
{property_identifier: 84, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Polarity'}
{property_identifier: 0, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Acked Transitions'}
{property_identifier: 4, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Active Text'}
{property_identifier: 6, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Alarm Value'}
{property_identifier: 15, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Change Of State Count'}
{property_identifier: 16, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Change Of State Time'}
{property_identifier: 17, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Notification Class'}
{property_identifier: 28, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Description'}
{property_identifier: 31, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Device Type'}
{property_identifier: 33, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Elapsed Active Time'}
{property_identifier: 35, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Enable'}
{property_identifier: 46, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Inactive Text'}
{property_identifier: 72, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Notify Type'}
{property_identifier: 103, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Reliability'}
{property_identifier: 113, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Time Delay'}
{property_identifier: 115, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Time Of State Count Reset'}
{property_identifier: 130, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Time Stamps'}
{property_identifier: 168, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Profile Name'}
{property_identifier: 351, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Message Texts'}
{property_identifier: 352, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Message Texts Config'}
{property_identifier: 353, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Detection Enable'}
{property_identifier: 354, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Event Algorithm Inhibit'}
{property_identifier: 356, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Time Delay Normal'}
{property_identifier: 357, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Reliability Evaluation Inhibit'}
{property_identifier: 485, property_value: {…}, property_identifier_name: 'Profile Location'}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to group rows based on property_identifier which have number value i want to group them based on number range 0 to 150 will show in "General", 151 to 250 in "Alarm", and rest in hestorian and these thing i want to show data just like image in expand and collapse format and i am getting api response which having field property_identifier